# Raspberry Pi: Starting chromium in fullscreen kiosk

Tags: chromium, lxde, raspberry-pi-desktop, kiosk

On the raspberry pi desktop bootup, I want chromium to start in fullscreen kiosk mode where it also cover the raspberry pi menu panel.

I can't get chromium to go overtop of the menu panel. So I made it so the panel minimizes when not in use and I set the minimized size to 0. But now when I run chromium, it's offset by the original size of the panel, it won't go to the top of the screen..

I also tried disabling the panel:
#@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi

But it's still the same, there's a blank space at the top.

```
    # start lxpanel with profile LXDE-pi, should be standard
    @lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
    # start filemanager with profile LXDE-pi, should be standard
    @pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
    # don't start xscreensaver
    #@xscreensaver -no-splash
    # turn the screen saver functions off
    @xset s off
    # sets the preference to display a pattern rather than blank the video
    @xset s noblank
    # disables DPMS (Energy Star) features
    @xset -dpms
    # suppress error message after unexpected reboot
    @sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
    # start chromium in kiosk mode
    @chromium --noerrdialogs --disable-translate --start-fullscreen --kiosk --incognito http://www.google.com
```

[image: screenshot of raspberry pi desktop running chromium in fullscreen kiosk mode]